# Compare two tables and return colum names which are not equal in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Tables which are, `TS_SALES` and `TS_SALES_AUDIT`.

Here `TS_SALES` is parent table and `TS_SALES_AUDIT` is child table.

when i count the columns in two tables using below code,

```
1) SELECT count(*) FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES';
   ---------
   Count(*)
   ---------
      130

2) SELECT count(*) FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES_AUDIT';
   ---------
   Count(*)
   ---------
      40
```

Can we return the column names which are not equal in both tables?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Formatted text please, not images.

Comment: @jarlh, Hi, it is code only not the image.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

Columns that are in `TS_SALES` but not in `TS_SALES_AUDIT`

```
SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES'
minus 
SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES_AUDIT'
```

Columns that are in `TS_SALES_AUDIT` but not in `TS_SALES`

```
 SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES_AUDIT'
 minus 
 SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES'
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select max(table_name) as which_table_name,
       max(column_name) as which_column_name
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name in ('TS_SALES', 'TS_SALES_AUDIT')
group by column_name
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the columns that exist in TS_SALES and not in TS_SALES_AUDIT, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES_AUDIT'
)
```

To achieve the reverse, use the following:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES_AUDIT' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TS_SALES'
)
```